# Vertex AI Evaluation fails at batch prediction step

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to run Vertex AI evaluation of a model trained via a custom container. The model is available in the model registry. The batch prediction step of the evaluation fails even if I succeed to run batch prediction jobs.
[Evaluation pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp8u4.png)

The error is due to an internal service account (custom-batch-prediction@.....iam.gserviceaccount.com) lacking access to the model file (model.pkl) in a GCS bucket.

I tried to create an evaluation using the GCP Console. I selected a BigQuery table as input, the output location, class names etc. Then I specified the Compute Engine default service account as service account to be used. This account has all the required IAM permissions [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/evaluation/using-model-evaluation?hl=en#prerequisites).

However, the evaluation pipeline fails at the batch prediction step "model-batch-predict". In the logs I got this error:

```
error: 403 GET
https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/***/o/models%2F[folder name removed for confidentiality]%2F2024-01-28_040503%2Fmodel%2Fmodel.pkl?alt=media: 
custom-batch-prediction@[removed]-tp.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have  storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
Permission &#39;storage.objects.get&#39; denied on resource (or it  may not exist).: 
('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected  one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>),  type: <class 'google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden'>
```

I had to remove a few parts (between brackets) for confidentiality.
So Vertex AI uses an internal service account (custom-batch-prediction@) but I don't understand how it doesn't inherit the permissions to read the model file from the Compute Engine default service account.

The code that reads the model.pkl is pretty straightforward and works in the case of simple batch prediction.

```
    client = storage.Client(project=project_name)
    bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(object_path)
    model_bytes = blob.download_as_bytes()
    model = pickle.loads(model_bytes)
```

Comment: When you create the Evaluation, which service account did you specify?   Is it `custom-batch-prediction@.....iam.gserviceaccount.com` or you left blank, if you left blank, then Vertex AI evaluation will use the default service account. To answer your other question, custom service account (custom-batch-prediction@.....iam.gserviceaccount.com) wouldn't automatically inherit the Compute Engine Default service account permissions, you have to grant the permission to it.

Comment: Add details on how you specified `custom-batch-prediction@[removed]-tp.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as the service account to use. Include a list of IAM roles for that service account. Also, note that service accounts do not inherit permissions from other service accounts. Inheritance is Organization -> Folder -> Project -> resource, not resource -> resource.

Comment: "_Then I specified the Compute Engine default service account as service account to be used._ "
I only specified the Compute Engine default SA.  The `custom-batch-prediction@...` SA is unknown to me, I believe it's created internally by Vertex AI to perform the batch prediction. I don't see it when I go to IAM.